# Normalizing variables in two dimensions?

Tags: normalization

Let's say you had two hiking paths, A and B, and you were looking at the typical time to travel each relative to the other.

Let's say there's two groups of people, young (Y) and old (O).  Let's say young people typically take path A and old people typically take path B.

Say the average time in minutes is mapped in the following matrix:
{A,Y}: 20
{A,O}: 30
{B,Y}: 10
{B,O}: 25

Let's also say the number of observations is mapped in the following matrix:
{A,Y}: 100
{A,O}: 25
{B,Y}: 40
{B,O}: 300

I am struggling because I don't think I want to compare weighted averages.  Those will be biased.  I have an inkling that I want to decompose the matrices somehow, but I'm not totally sure how.

Ideally, I'd like to say something like "relative to path A, path B takes 1.3x as long".  Or alternatively, "relative to old people, young people walk 1.2x as fast".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that isn't already apparent in your matrix?  You don't seem actually to tell us what your question is.

Comment: The last line:  Ideally, I'd like to say something like "relative to path A, path B takes 1.3x as long". Or alternatively, "relative to old people, young people walk 1.2x as fast".

Comment: If you're going to avoid qualifying your statements, then implicitly (in the omnibus phrase "typical time") you *are* taking a weighted average.  I don't see any way to avoid that.  Why not just break down your results as indicated in the table: "for young people, path B takes $x$ times longer, while for older people, path B takes $y$ times longer"?